# Face detection using EMGU CV in c#

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am doing face detection using `Emgu CV` in c#. It's a windows form application `WFP`.The code doesn't have any compile errors but doesn't detect any faces in the image and there is a `Null reference exception` thrown by a `DetectHaarCascade` function at run time.
The below is the code snippet

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (open.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Image img = Image.FromFile(open.FileName);
           pictureBox1.Image = img;
            Image<Bgr, byte> ImageFrame = new Image<Bgr, byte>(new Bitmap(img));
           pictureBox1.Image = ImageFrame.ToBitmap();
              if (ImageFrame != null)
              {
                  Image<Gray, byte> grayframe = ImageFrame.Convert<Gray, byte>();
                  try
                  {
                      MCvAvgComp[][] faces = grayframe.DetectHaarCascade(haar, 1.4, 4, HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING, new Size(ImageFrame.Width / 8, ImageFrame.Height / 8));


                      foreach (MCvAvgComp face in faces[0])
                      {
                          ImageFrame.Draw(face.rect, new Bgr(Color.Green), 3);
                      }
```

I have also added all the references required of Emgu dll files,and also added all the openCV dll files to the debug folder of the project.
I am using `visual studio 2010`and
            `Emgu CV 2.4`.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: After I install Emgu CV with NuGet, the `DetectHaarCascade` method is missing on the `Image<Gray, byte>` object.